# Flutter Release APK is not displaying content properly whereas Debug APK is working perfectly

Tags: flutter, debugging, release, android-app-bundle

When I'm exporting the APK or AAB of Flutter app, debug version is working great on all devices. But the release version is not working properly. It doesn't display any of the elements properly except images. I have attached a screenshot for reference.

I have tried multiple ways to figure this out.
I have tried with exporting apk with --no-shrink, filtered out x86 version for AAB, enabled internet permission also in Manifest file but it's still not fixed.

Please help.
Here is the app link on PlayStore : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theneondesign.flikko

[Release version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jhen.png)
[Debug version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovPIL.png)

Update 22nd November 2022:
I figured out the exact issue but not the solution.

The issue is, I'm using height and width in some of the elements.
I'm getting the height and size from Get.context!.height and Get.context!.width

Get.context is not working in release and only works in debug.
Can you help me a way to resolve this?
I have already tried with Mediaquery but as the height and width are in a separate class, I cannot use BuildContext. I tried window size also, but it doesn't work as well. I'm new to Flutter, so I couldn't figure out any other way.

Comment: please check to run in release apk using `flutter run --release`

Comment: I tried doing that. It's the same issue again.